# How to get a CIImage to render over its own source bitmap?

Tags: ios, core-image

Let's assume a `CIImage` created by applying a color filter to a source bitmap. The pixels of the result are not fully opaque, i.e. alpha may be less than 1.

I'd like to render the `CIImage` back to the source bitmap, completely replacing the existing pixel data. The approaches I tried that didn't work were

1. Clearing the pixel data in the bitmap before rendering the `CIImage` to it. This doesn't work because the `CIImage` lazily computes its result, and as the bitmap is also the source image, the `CIImage` sees an empty source bitmap.
2. Creating a `CIRenderDestination` for the bitmap, setting its blending mode, and rendering the `CIImage` to it. This failed with an error code 4 (not sure what that means, but presumably it has to do with the source and destination pointing to the same data.)

The approach that would undoubtedly work is to use an intermediate bitmap to cache the result of the `CIImage`. But I'm *really* trying hard to avoid this, since Core Image has been designed to minimize intermediate results.

What other approaches might work here? (Keep in mind, the output of the `CIImage` is not fully opaque.)

Comment: I'm afraid Core Image is not designed to apply filters on image buffers _in place_. The only thing that buffers results is an `CIImageAccumulator`, but that would also create its own data buffer on creation. But you can at least use it to continuously update that data.